# Why can't I run my Regulafalsi code? Because of NoneType error

Tags: python, equation-solving

Here is my code for one of the root-finding methods.

```
from __future__ import division
def falseposition(f, a, b, imax=50, tolerance=1.0e-10):
  i = 0
  while i < imax:
    c = (a*f(b)-b*f(a))/(f(b) - f(a))
    if c == 0 or f(c) < tolerance:
      return c, i
    elif (f(a)*f(c))<0:
      b=c
    else:
      a=c
    i += 1
f = lambda x: x**5 - x + 1
root, steps = falseposition(f, 1, 8)
print ("The root is", root, "and the value is", f(root), "; steps taken:", steps)
```

There is a TypeError. It says that 'NoneType' object is not iterable.

If you see what's the problem, please, tell.

Comment: What happens if the first `if` condition is never satisfied? You should take that into account.

Comment: Its easier for people to help when you post the complete error message you get.

Comment: If you reach your iteration limit, the function falls off the end, implicitly returning `None`.  The error occurs when trying to unpack this `None` into `root` and `steps`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `falseposition` function *only* explicitely returns when it finds a value of `c` that meets the criterion *before* `i` gets greater than `imax`. If it doesn't, then it falls out of the while loop, reaches the end of the function body and then (implicitely) returns `None`. When that's the case, the `root, steps = falseposition(f, 1, 8)` statement effectively becomes `root, steps = None`, and since `None` is not iterable you get this error.

You mainly have two solutions here, either:

return `None, i` as default at the end of the function (with `None` signaling the function failed to found a matching value for `c`):

```
def falseposition(f, a, b, imax=50, tolerance=1.0e-10):
  i = 0
  while i < imax:
    c = (a*f(b)-b*f(a))/(f(b) - f(a))
    if c == 0 or f(c) < tolerance:
      return c, i
    elif (f(a)*f(c))<0:
      b=c
    else:
      a=c
    i += 1
  # nothing found
  return None, i
```

or raise some exception instead (and let the caller code catch it):

```
def falseposition(f, a, b, imax=50, tolerance=1.0e-10):
  i = 0
  while i < imax:
    c = (a*f(b)-b*f(a))/(f(b) - f(a))
    if c == 0 or f(c) < tolerance:
      return c, i
    elif (f(a)*f(c))<0:
      b=c
    else:
      a=c
    i += 1
  # nothing found
  raise ValueError("No matching c value")
```

Which of those solutions makes sense depends on the context and whatnot,  but since obviously there might be quite a few cases where no proper "solution" will be found the first one (returning (`None`, i)`) seems a good candidate.

You could of course leave the function as is and make sure you test the return value before trying to unpack it:

```
result = falseposition(f, 1, 8)
if result is None:
   print("oops, nothing found")
root, steps = result
# etc
```

but that's really really ugly, and bad practice actually (one expects the return value of a function to be of consistant type).